# What is the easiest way to "finish off" small residual balances from a prepaid debit card?

Tags: cash

I have two debit cards in my wallet that I'd love to get rid of... sitting on a thick wallet in the car and at the office becomes quite annoying, so I try to minimize what I carry.

The problem with these debit cards is that one has a balance of $1.40 and the other has a balance of $7.20.  Small balances like these are hard to use, and I typically end up throwing these things away when they get to less than $2.00.

What is the best way to finish off small balances on prepaid debit cards?

Comment: Hello. This question is off-topic here as it doesn't require a life hack as defined by our site [here](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might have a better chance of getting a quality answer on [Money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com/). If you want to read more about our site, see our [help center](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/). Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't agree.  These cards seem to be designed to be difficult to empty, and many carry service fees if they're not used in a specific amount of time.  This is not a "finance and money" type of issue, but a very practical real-world problem with no intuitive solution.

Comment: We've had questions related to these cards on Money.SE (Personal Finance) before. If it were posted there, I would answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to 7-11 and buy something that costs more.   Give them cash for the difference.

You will need to figure out exactly how much is left on the card.  So if it's 1.87 and you buy something that is 2.00 .  you give the clerk 13 cents and tell him you want to put the rest on your card.  Problem solved.

Also, if you have more than $5, you can get cash back from 7-11 when you make a purchase.  Sometimes I buy a 25 cent candy just to get 5 or 10 bucks off my card.